# ScrollView with weight not working for me

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a parent linearlayout with two scrollview inside it and I am using weight attribute inside scroll vies but this is not working for me I mean it's not providing any scrolling. Here is the code, how can I make it work?

```
LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutSizes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/product_detail_items_margin_left"
            >
        </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutColors"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/colorsGroup"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </RadioGroup>
         </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add Linear layout as a parent on scroll view and try

Comment: @Pravin Nops,still not working

Comment: have you added for both scroll views

Comment: yes i added for both ?

Comment: do you have scrollable contents. Means add many components in it like textview, imageview and then test

Comment: @Pravin yes i have content i both scroll views, i am adding content at run time

Comment: make inner `LinearLayout`'s (linearLayoutColors & linearLayoutSizes) width to `match_parent` for both `scrollview` and It will start scrolling.

Comment: android:fillViewport="true" user this property in scrollview

Comment: do you want vertical scrolling or horizontal scrolling ?

Comment: @user2934930, By looking at your code, I believe what you need is HorizontalScrollView instead of ScrollView. I have put my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/36419158/3286489

Comment: your code does not have any problem . but please be specific on what do you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimented your code and found the issue.

From your code, it does seems like what you want is a Horizontal Scroll. But you are using normal ScrollView which is by default Vertical Scroll. Consider changing ScrollView to HorizontalScrollView.

i.e. from

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp">
```

to

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp">
```

Do change on both your scroll view. Cheers!

Comment: Oh man, yeah that was the issue i though when set android:scrollbar="horizontal" it will scroll horizontally, Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Since you are fixing weight for the scrollView it thinks that the data should never exceed the height and hence it doesnt scroll. Just cover the scrollviews with frame layouts like below and try.

```
    LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

   <FrameLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutSizes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/product_detail_items_margin_left"
        >
    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
   <FrameLayout>

     <FrameLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutColors"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/colorsGroup"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </RadioGroup>
     </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
  </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

See if this works.

Comment: should i remove the weight attribute from the scrollview?

Comment: yes and set it to frame layout and check. Since you are adding content at run time, there might be some issues. Just try this approach and let me know

Comment: is the view you are adding visible and height is more than screen size?

Comment: Yes they are visible and not height actually width should me more than size because I'm scrolling horizontally here

Comment: @Thanks for your help Elye suggestion worked from. Upvote for you help

Answer (score 0):

See if the following code works for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutSizes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutColors"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/colorsGroup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

your XML looks ok to me so why dont you try and add a couple of buttons or images to the layouts and try to scroll them?

also dont forget to add this line of code to the very top of your XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

let me know how you get on.